# Azure App Provisioning: Filtering on multivalued attribute emails[type work"]

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, provisioning, microsoft-entra-id

I have a .NET service with a SCIM project. This is for App Provisioning (Azure/Entra ID), SCIM 2.0, provisioning users from the customer's Azure Active Directory, into my MySQL database.

However, a user can also be created manually in on my platform, and will therefore not have an ObjectId, only an Email. The Provisioning Service will (before creating a new user), check if one already exists with the same ObjectId, and then insert additional data coming from the attributes in the scope for provisioning if that is the case.

```
                        //ExternalId filter
                        else if (andFilter.AttributePath.Equals(AttributeNames.ExternalIdentifier
                                     , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            if (andFilter.FilterOperator != ComparisonOperator.Equals)
                            {
                                throw new NotSupportedException(
                                    string.Format(
                                        SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementServiceResources
                                            .ExceptionFilterOperatorNotSupportedTemplate, andFilter.FilterOperator));
                            }

                            var externalIdentifier = andFilter.ComparisonValue;

                            if (!Guid.TryParse(externalIdentifier, out var uniqueIdentifier))
                            {
                                return Enumerable.Empty<Resource>().ToArray();
                            }

                            predicate = predicate.And(a =>
                                a.ObjectId == uniqueIdentifier || a.Uuid == uniqueIdentifier);
                        }
```

Now, I want to do the same with Email. However, when adding presedence for the source mapping in the Provisioning overview:
[image]

I get a really strange value from for the email attribute name, when i do the same thing for Email:

```
// Email filter
                        else if (andFilter.AttributePath.Equals(AttributeNames.EmailAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            if (andFilter.FilterOperator != ComparisonOperator.Equals)
                            {
                                throw new NotSupportedException(
                                    string.Format(
                                        SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementServiceResources
                                            .ExceptionFilterOperatorNotSupportedTemplate, andFilter.FilterOperator));
                            }

                            string? email = andFilter.ComparisonValue.Substring(17);
                            predicate = predicate.And(a => a.Email.Equals(email));
                        }
```

In order for the above to work, I had to add a really awkward Attribute name the the AttributeNames class:

```
public const string EmailAddress = "emails[type";
```

This is the value that comes out of `andFilter.AttributePath`
It gets even more weird when looking at the `andFilter.ComparisonValue` which is `work"].value eq "email123@dingdong.onmicrosoft.com` Which is not what i want to compare with when looking for the user. This is why i have the  `string? email = andFilter.ComparisonValue.Substring(17);` to remove the first 17 characters to only look up the email.

However, is there not a better way? It must be possible to easily recieve a multivalued attribute for email and look it up? What am I doing wrong?